# How to get state of an aggregate in CQRS pattern?

Tags: akka, cqrs

According the article of Martin Fowler and *Microsoft CQRS Journey*, the CQRS is a pattern applying in a BC, not the architecture for whole system. I get confused in how to get state of an aggregate from anything external in CQRS.

**Should an aggregate have a command `Get` to return its state in write model, or a corresponding query in read model?**

It's example of shopping cart service in [Akka Platform Guide](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/akka-platform-guide/microservices-tutorial/complete-entity.html).

`ShoppingCart` is an aggregate, it has three commands: `AddItem`, `Checkout` and `Get`. In the command handler of `Get`, it replies summary of shopping cart to the command sender. In this way, each aggregate has a command `Get` to return its state in write model.

But I suppose the `Get` is a query exactly, not a command. Because in CQRS pattern, command changes the state of the aggregate and triggers events, but returns nothing. On the other side, query returns a copy of the current state of the aggregate, but changes nothing. All commands exist in write model, all queries exist in read model. If I want to get state, I shouldn't send a command to write model but a query to read model. The eventually consistence is maintained by the event projection from write model to read model.

So, the `Get` of `ShoppingCart` should be moved into read model. Anything external wants to get the state of `ShoppingCart`, it should send query `Get` to `ShoppingCart` and get reply `Summary` finally. But in this way, the state maybe is stale. Should it get problem in consistence?

**Which design is necessary and better?**

Putting `Get` in read model gets risk of consistence, putting it in write model gets semantic ambiguity otherwise. That's my confusion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the reply from the team.

They demonstrate the `Get` command on the write-side for multiple reasons:

1. show the feature of handling a command that produces no events.
2. exemplify that sometimes consistency is required and that’s possible within the scope of a single aggregate.

So that's it.

Answer (score 1):

> Putting Get in read model gets risk of consistency, putting it in write model gets semantic ambiguity otherwise. That's my confusion.

First, a reality check; the time between when these pixels appear on your screen, and when your eye sees them, is about a nanosecond.  So the answer you are looking at is at least that old.  It's going to take what, at least a millisecond? to hop across a network.

In other words, the query response is already old.  The only way to ensure that it is still an accurate representation of the *current* state of the aggregate would be to lock out all commands until you are done looking at it.

You *can* do that if you have to, but there are trade offs.  The situations where locking is the appropriate choice to make are, from what I can tell, rare.  But if you need it, you need it.  Note: you're probably going to have to give up CQRS in that case.

---

A more flexible framing is that the query handler returns, not a representation of the aggregate "now", but a representation of the aggregate at some specific point in the (recent) past.

So I send some query at 12:02, and what I get back is a copy of the report that was prepared based on a copy of the aggregate's state at 12:00.  And I, the client, know that, because at the top of the report there is an announcement in big friendly letters saying "this report was prepared at 12:00".

---

This can open up a lot of interesting questions, because now you are talking about time, and SLOs (is an up to the minute report good enough, or do we need something more recent? how long can we cache the report, vs checking for an updated version? are we willing to trade some extra response latency to get a more recent version?  What should happen in the system when no updated version of the report is available?)

---

> I'm not sure if it should put a command Get into write model to return state of aggregate. I prefer to add query Get into read model

That's how I would do it - the query handler loads a copy of the "read model" and collects the information from it.  The "write model" would not be loaded.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with you that result of query always is stale in CQRS pattern. But I'm not sure if it should put a command `Get` into write model to return state of aggregate. I prefer to add query `Get` into read model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Akka but here's how I see it:

Eventual consistency is not between the write and read side, but between replications in a distributed system (projections, read models, indices etc).

There's little point in having Get-support in write models because read and write don't have to be consistent with each other. They don't have to use the same concepts at all. Read models can even be projections of multiple aggregates (in theory). Sometimes however, it is useful to have simpler transient projections in the write models, but they should only be used during write operations and not exposed for pure reads.

Remember, the only purpose of a write model is to project just enough state to be able to handle and validate a command, and produce an event. That's it.

I'm not sure I answered your question but this is how I look at consistency and read/write models etc. Anyway, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thank you. My confusion is about CQRS pattern, not the example of Akka itself. In CQRS pattern, write side implements all the domain logics, read side offers material queries. The write side maintains the state of aggregate, then persists events and projects events to read side. The read side consumes the projected events and updates   the material tables. After then, client sends query to read side and presents the result. That's the eventually consistence between write side and read side.

Comment: But if the write model cannot be queried, why do we need to think of consistency between it and the read model? I don't think the read side can present "stale" state, because the state is what the read side says it is.

Comment: If a user takes action on what it think is the latest state and someone else got there first and modified it (or it was already modified but not projected yet, or...) then there are a bunch of options; optimistic concurrency, merge, exception etc depending on the command being handled. But there's not really any inconsistency to speak about here? The write side is internal/secret state just for the purpose of validating commands. The true state is the read model and it's always consistent (unless replicated). But I see what you are pointing at...

Comment: The kernel idea of CQRS pattern is to separate a aggregate into write side and read side. At the write side, it updates the state with single writer principle. The validation logic is implemented in write side also. By implementation, both the command and event include a field `Version`, it's a important field for concurrent conflicts. It's a complex subject in CQRS pattern.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

While you are interested with the Akka Framework and CQRS Pattern, you should check another part of the Akka Framework, [Akka Projections](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-projection/current/overview.html).

As you mentioned, realising the command part of the CQRS in Akka makes super sense but Query part with Command like 'Get' is awkward, plus you can do get sensefully only for ActorId for any other query form you have to do really inefficient things.

Akka Projection can use out of the box, a JDBC datasource, Apache Cassandra, etc to give you more scalability but also more flexibility about how you can shape your queries, the problem with eventual consistency would be there but that is something to be judged from use case to use case.

I used the same principle in my blog and if you want to see have it is done, you can check there. As a bonus there you will see that I implemented Akka Projection with Elasticsearch there which is not available out of the box for Akka Projections, [blog1](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/05/17/akka-projections-and-elasticearch/) [blog2](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/04/18/a-model-driven-event-sourced-cloud-ready-application-with-akka-finite-state-machine-using-kafka-cassandra-and-elasticsearch/).